# How to show form elements within PDF by print module?

Tags: forms

I'm using the [print](https://drupal.org/project/print) module to convert a node to a PDF. I see that there is the print.tpl.php for theming, but where can I say that I want to show form elements (eg. input fields, radiobuttons, ..) within the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you mean but you can show / hide elements via the ui.

1. go to **admin/structure/types/manage/your-content-type/display**
2. Under Custom Display Settings enable Print
3. **admin/structure/types/manage/page/your-content-type/print**

This will show or hide form elements for the pdf version as well as the print version.